# Getting "Array element cannot be nil" from Analyzer as a false-positive

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang-static-analyzer

I have a case where the XCode analyzer is flagging valid code.

We have an NSString category with a method `isEmpty` which checks if the string is empty, including checking for a nil string.  When it's used in combination with adding the string to an array, the analyzer complains:

```
if (![NSString isEmpty:myString]) {
    [_myArray addObject:myString];
}
```

The analyzer will then complain with `Array element cannot be nil`, because it isn't smart enough to detect that `isEmpty` is preventing that.

What's the best workaround? I know I can change the condition to `if (myString && ![NSString isEmpty...` but that seems like a clunky workaround.

EDIT:  By request, here's the body of `isEmpty`:

```
+ (BOOL)isEmpty:(NSString *)string
{
    return (string ? [string isEqualToString:@""] : YES); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that you have to show the analyzer every possible logical path. Your "workaround" is perfectly good.

It might be that your `isEmpty` could be written to help the analyzer more, but you didn't show that, so it's impossible to say. Based on what you've actually shown, I would suggest that you just use your "workaround" and move on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've added the body of `isEmpty` to the original posting... it's very simple.

Comment: Thanks; I haven't tested your implementation, but I stand by my answer: if you have to be more explicit in order to quiet the analyzer, then be more explicit. (And file a bug report if you feel strongly about it.)

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C the easiest way to check for `non-nil` and `non-empty` for `NSString` is to get the `length`. It returns 0 for `nil` and `empty` and the proper length for `non-empty`.

```
NSString *testNil = nil;
NSString *testEmpty = @"";
NSString *testNonEmpty = @"Hello";

NSInteger testNilLength = [testNil length]; // -> 0
NSInteger testEmptyLength = [testEmpty length]; // -> 0
NSInteger testNonEmptyLength = [testNonEmpty length]; // -> 5
```

Comment: That's a nice little trick.  the `isEmpty` category method predates me and is pretty prevalent in the code, so if possible I'd like to keep using it so as not to disrupt the codebase too much.

Comment: Actually it benefits from the fact that in Objective-C sending a message to `nil` does nothing / results `nil` and `nil` is implicitly casted to 0 if the sending type is a scalar.